# How to get entire no of rows present in data table into single label using button click event in window form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

How to get entire rows present in data table into single label(for every row we should not take new label,we should take only single label for "N" no of rows present in datatable)  using button click event in window form c#

```
        for (int i = 1, r = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++, r++)
        {
            label19.Text = Convert.ToInt32(i).ToString();
            label20.Text = dt.Rows[r]["Ques"].ToString();
          }
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: for (int i = 1, r = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++, r++)
        {
            Label line = new Label();
            line.Text = "<hr width='100%'>";
            label19.Text = Convert.ToInt32(i).ToString();
            label20.Text = dt.Rows[r]["Ques"].ToString();
          } @ByteNudger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For All Rows and columns

```
line.Text = "";
for(int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        line.Text +=dt.Rows[i][j].ToString()+" ";
    }
    line.Text +=Environment.NewLine;
}
```

this should work
for your example

```
for(int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
line.Text +=(i+1).ToString()+" "+dt.Rows[i]["Ques"].ToString()+" ";
line.Text +=Environment.NewLine;
}
```

you can format it To Look Porper in web project

```
line.Text ="<table>";
for(int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    line.Text ="<tr>";
    for(int j = 0; j<dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        line.Text +="<td>"+dt.Rows[i][j].ToString()+"</td>";
    }
    line.Text +="</tr>";
}
line.Text +="</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my requirement is quite different all questions are present in single line but i need in row by row @VISHMAY

Comment: thanks :) need some more help from you for every question their will be four radio buttons and labels but now i should not take radio buttons and labels from window desgin by programming itself we must create radio buttons and labels. is it possible to do in window form @VISHMAY

Comment: is it possible to do with my requirement ?? @VISHMAY

Comment: @user2837291 it is possible to do this with your requirement. but cannot explain in comments. please ask this as other question so that both question does not mix up